# How to print AmazonEC2 Slave details via groovy script in Jenkins Script Console

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cloudbees

I am using CloudBees Jenkins. We are configuring dynamic runners (or slaves) via AmazonEC2 Plugin where we mention runner details like AMI ID, Key, Region, Labels etc and the runners are created based on that information.

I want to write a Groovy Script that I want to run in Jenkins Script Console to see the details of all such runner details configured.

I can see that all the information I need is stored in `hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate` class.

But I cant see any method to get this class instance. I have managed to write this one which only prints the labels of the configured slaves

```
Jenkins.instance.clouds
Jenkins.instance.clouds.each {
 
println it.name
}
```

Can anyone help to print all (or atleast some like AMI ID, region etc) via groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. Sharing here if this is helpful to other people:

```
import hudson.plugins.ec2.AmazonEC2Cloud
import hudson.plugins.ec2.SlaveTemplate
import hudson.slaves.Cloud
import com.cloudbees.opscenter.client.cloud.CloudImpl


Jenkins.instance.clouds.each {
  
  if(!(it instanceof CloudImpl)){
    
    
    Cloud cloud = it
    AmazonEC2Cloud ac = cloud
    
    List<SlaveTemplate>  stL = ac.getTemplates()
    
    for (SlaveTemplate st : stL){
      
      if(st == null){
       println "SlaveTemplate is null" 
      } else{
       
        println st.ami
        println st.labels 
      }
      
    }
    
    
  }
```

If you want to print more details about your configured slaves, the `class attribute` names can be found at https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/ec2/hudson/plugins/ec2/SlaveTemplate.html